# Keybinding for adding a new heading under a list item in org-mode

Tags: org-mode, key-bindings, outline

Lets say you are working in an org-mode structure like this:

```
* First level heading…
** Second level heading
*** Third level heading
- list item one
- list item two
```

After list item two you want to insert a new third level heading instead of another list item. Of course you can type Return and 3 times * yet I wonder if there is a command with a keybinding to do that.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP regrets posing it and wants to delete it.

Answer (score 1):

Ooops, I should have tried harder before posting this question:

```
C-return
```

does the trick. Sorry for asking.